# GridView and localize AutoGenerate?????Button text

Tags: localization, asp.net-2.0

Is there a way to localize the text of the button that is automatically generated?

The Edit / Insert / Delete / Cancel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer, I had to visit [.NET Framework Version 2.0 Language Pack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa731542.aspx) to download it.